# Facebook like plugin with dot in name

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get facebook like plugin from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/. In the "Url to like" section when I add [www.facebook.com/riyasat.ali.16](http://www.facebook.com/riyasat.ali.16) it just does not work or display the like button. But when I type [www.facebook.com/newyork](http://www.facebook.com/newyork) it works fine.

And now if I type any name that has dot(.) in the name is not working or not displaying any like button even on the developers page. Please help me how to fix it.

Note: All the work I am doing is on facebook developers page.

Comment: not an expert, but i would guess you need to escape the dot?

Answer (score 1):

You are fundamentally misunderstanding what the Like Button plugin is and how it works.

You're trying to point the Like button at a personal facebook profile. This will not work. The like button is for liking external URLs and Facebook Pages, not profiles.